# GameMaker Studio 2 - Object changes to different sprite without programming (GML)

Tags: gml, game-maker-studio-2

While programming my game, I came up on a significant issue. I am trying to create a tactical game, and I created grid cell objects for it. In the object's step event, it has the following code to change the sprite index when the mouse hovers over it.

```
if (position_meeting(mouse_x,mouse_y,OBJ_GridCell))
{
    sprite_index = 1;
}
else
{
    sprite_index = 0;
}
```

This is what the intended sprite looks like (set in object properties):[image: What the sprite should look like.]

But then when I run the game, it changes to another sprite I have, and the code functions like it should. It just is the wrong sprite.
[image: The output.]

I have tried searching, but I can't find anything that matches my issue. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to pick a different frame inside a sprite, so you should use `image_index` instead of `sprite_index`.

`image_index` decided which frame in the sprite will be picked, where `sprite_index` let you choose a different sprite.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.